# Commands not working, and trying to add a queue/ability to add playlists

Tags: python, discord, youtube, audio-player

I'm trying to make a music bot for discord, everything appears to be working. It's turning on and detects the prefix, but when I do "?join" so it joins the Voice Channel it tells me "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found. Below is the code that I've used for the bot

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    
    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
    
    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.channel.send("Paused")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.channel.send("Resume")

def setup(client):
    
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

I'm unsure of what to do to fix this, I've tried looking up solutions but I either don't understand the code or it's not in the same "style" as the code that I have.

If someone could also help me integrate the ability to play playlists & queues into the bot, I'm once again lost on this since I have little to no experience with this, so any help would also be greatly appreciated. I figured I'd ask on the same post since all the code that I think is necessary to figure it out would already be here.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: `bot.add_command`

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand what to do with this information. I read the page to try to understand the line of code and then I tried including bot.add_command(join) but it's telling me that "bot" is an unidentified name. Am I missing something? I've included it in the same way that the page has included it in their code.

Comment: Did you define `bot` like `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')`? Always RTFM!

Comment: I had that but "Client" instead of "bot" originally. Now that I changed it it's telling me that the syntax is incorrect even though I have it the same way as the website and the way that you did it "def bot.add_command(join)" and have it underneath the line "await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)"